# Como consigo fazer um temporizador em Python que ao final do timer emita algum som qualquer?

Tags: python

```
import time

def tempo():
    time.sleep(10)    
    print "Ola"
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar winsound e especificar o som que deseja

```python
import winsound
import time

def tempo():
    time.sleep(3.0)
    winsound.PlaySound('C:/Users/usuario/Downloads/sound.wav',winsound.SND_ALIAS)

tempo()
```

Comment: Perfeito!!!

Obrigado!